# How to make RecyclerView with navigation in depth?

Tags: java, android, database, android-recyclerview

Here is an example from the McDonalds application, where in the menu fragment there is a RecyclerView, when you click on any element of which the exact same RecyclerView appears (only with a changed content, which depends on the selected element), and the next time it repeats. How can you implement exactly the same navigation? (and how to transfer data about the selected button in such a complex structure) Who has already encountered this? Data coming from sql.

[McDonalds example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jekBF.png)

Answer (score 2):

I've just downloaded and checked this app. So, that's what I think.

It looks like the Menu tab is `Fragment`. Let's call it `MenuMainFragment`. Clicking on, for example, Drinks we are going to open something like `MenuGroupFragment` and our previous fragment adds to backstack. While we are in `MenuGroupFragment` we can also click on any element and finally `MenuItemsFragment` appears (`MenuGroupFragment` is also going to backstack). Clicking on any element here makes us to open `ItemActivity` obviously. So there are 3 levels of depth in any case. In my opinion all fragments in our "flow" are creating by passing some information into it. For example in `MenuGroupFragment` we pass something like "subgroupId" and then find everything that relates this "subgroupId" in our database and so on. As for me it's the most obvious case.

The less obvious case could be having only one `Fragment` with it's own flow-management, which is more harder and can be achieved by many different implementations. Probably, it can be achieved by having `Map<Int, List<Element>>`, where map's key is your step and value is list of elements related to this step. I think there will be some checks if it's first step or not to change the toolbar's icon, title and `onBackPressed()` behaviour.

Comment: Can you find an example of such a construction anywhere on the Internet? If you try to decompile this application, you can see that id is used there and lists are recreated by it.